# Shnayim Ushmonim Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred eighty-two?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

182 עוֹלוֹת were brought on סֻכּוֹת for סֻכּוֹת ‎(as opposed to, say, as תְּמִידִין or נְדָבוֹת‎): two rams and fourteen lambs daily (times seven days) and seventy bulls altogether.

Answer (score 3):

Noach was born when his father Lemech was 182.  (Breishis 5:28)

Answer (score 2):

182 is the numerical equivalent of Yakov.